# Скажите, нужна ли запятая перед "чтобы"?

Tags: синтаксис

Нужна ли запятая перед "чтобы" в предложении?

> Дайте мне что-нибудь, чтобы укрыться.

Answer (score 1):

Запятая нужна, СПП.
Сравните: *Дайте мне что-нибудь укрыться.* Здесь не нужна, простое предложение.

Answer (score 1):

***Дайте мне что-нибудь, чтобы укрыться.***

1) Это сложноподчиненное предложение (СПП) с придаточным цели, запятая ставится перед союзом ЧТОБЫ.

2)  Придаточное предложение является **односоставным безличным,** главный член выражен **независимым инфинитивом.** (Инфинитивные предложения характерны для СПП с придаточным цели).

3) С точки зрения стилистики предложение не очень удачное. Другой вариант: ***Дайте мне что-нибудь, чем можно укрыться***. Это СПП с придаточным определительным.

4) Варианты простого предложения (без запятой): ***Дайте чем-нибудь укрыться***.

*Дайте **что-нибудь укрыться**.* Это предложение также  не слишком удачно из-за неясной грамматики. Сравнить: Разве от него могло  ***что-нибудь укрыться***?

Comment: **3) С точки зрения стилистики предложение не очень удачное.** А объяснение будет? )

Comment: Объяснение несложное: повтор слова "что" и неясная семантика. Что хочет персонаж: чем-то укрыться или где-нибудь укрыться.

Comment: *Дайте мне что-нибудь, чтобы укрыться* - где здесь повтор слова "что"? А семантика неясна - для кого? Это живая разговорная фраза, таких в языке десятки тысяч. А вы вместо нее предлагаете какую-то длинную. Это чистая вкусовщина - "мне не нравится, и всё тут".

Comment: Интервью продолжается. Так Вы говорите, что здесь нет повтора слова? А "что" - это разве не слово? Оно входит в другие слова? Да какая разница, считайте тогда, что это не повтор, а тавтология. Смысл в том, что мы  слышим повтор, а это определяется на слух  как стилистическая некорректность. И ваш второй вопрос - о неясной семантике. Конечно, по ситуации видно, что человеку нужно, укрыться или спрятаться. Но мы интуитивно воспринимаем грамматическую неоднозначность и опять же определяем ее как стилистически некорректную. Всё,  благодарю Вас за вопросы, надеюсь, что Вам всё понятно.